# Extract steady state performance test results from Performance center or Load Runner Analysis through Rest API or Automation?

Tags: performance-testing, load-testing, loadrunner, hp-performance-center

Is there a way to automate extraction of steady state performance test results from Performance center or Load runner?

I couldn't do much with the templates, if anybody got success with this please share your thoughts.

Use case :-
We have an automation pipeline which runs performance tests through Rest API on performance center and post completion downloads the respective tests results in HTML format. But this HTML report is for the whole test duration while we want just the steady state part.

Our PE engineers use Load Runner Analysis (HP Analysis) on their local machines to extract the steady state from Raw Results(another result type which can be downloaded from Performance center through Rest API , just like HTML report mentioned above.)

I tried to do the same with Load Runner Analysis command line, but wasn't successful in parameterizing and applying a template for steady state.

I read somewhere(did it 6 months back, don't have the internet link now), that report templates can't be parameterized for time i.e. steady state.

Answer (score 0):

Using REST services, it is possible to extract the data, not the steady state. Please check [this](http://alm-help.saas.hpe.com/en/12.50/api_refs/Performance_Center_REST_API/Performance_Center_REST_API.htm) link.

For each run, the steady state time varies. Unless you knew the exact duration, it is not possible to filter.

Below trick will help you to apply the steady state without opening the Analysis. But make sure that you are 100% affirmative about the steady state duration.

1. Convert your steady state time in seconds. E.g. 1 minute 5 seconds to 65 seconds.
2. Go to your Analysis file `C:\Users\<ID>\Documents\VuGen\Analysis\<File-Name>`
3. Open `<File-Name>.asc` file in your favorite editor.
4. Search for `Scenario Elapsed Time` and add your start and end time of your steady state in `Dim_0` and `Dim_1` respectively. (You can write a macro as well to automate multiple files)

> ```
> `[SDFilter0]
> DimensionType=Continuous
> InternalDimName=End Time
> Dimension=Scenario Elapsed Time
> EqualFlag=1
> DimensionTableName=Event_meter
> NumValues=1
> DimCount=2
> Dim_0=65.000000
> Dim_1=122.000000`
> ```

5. Save the file.
6. Open your analysis file. Go to **`View > Summary Filter`** and then click on **OK**. You will see the steady state time as shown below.

[image: Summary Filter]

7. You should be able to see the steady state data.

Comment: Thanks for the response! But the question was to understand how to automate this?

Comment: @Kaus Please accept the answer if you find it useful.

Comment: I've already mentioned in the answer. You need to write a macro to get the steady state results.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing just that right now - automating the LR PC into our pipelines.

I'm using the REST API of the PC to trigger the collation and analysis phases. Once the test state is Finished, I'm downloading all the test results (the results.zip file), extracting it, opening the .mdb file and running a fat query inside to do exactly what the Analysis tool does and a bit more.

As for the Steady phase - sorry, but AFAIK there's no such term as a "steady phase" in this context. If you're running a stress test - what's the steady phase? :)
We've got a handful of test templates we're using. I'm analysing run results to find VU numbers and duration. Judging by those variables I'm determining which load test was that and then I know how long would the ramp-up, steady and r/dn durations be. Then some simple arithmetic et voila - you've got your Steady state timeframe.

The problem you'll probably some across is extracting and transforming the data from that MDB. It's got some nasty things to work around.